# Vertical Bar graph with Titles

Tags: android, graph

I am working on MPChart graph library where I am showing bar graph, with following code I am displaying a graph, but I want titles like: "Jan", "Feb" etc with them. How can I make a graph with title values?

```
 List<BarEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
        entries.add(new BarEntry(0f, 30f));
        entries.add(new BarEntry(1f, 80f));
        entries.add(new BarEntry(2f, 60f));
        entries.add(new BarEntry(3f, 50f));

        BarDataSet set = new BarDataSet(entries, "BarDataSet");
        BarData data = new BarData(set);
        data.setBarWidth(0.9f); // set custom bar width
        chart.setData(data);
        chart.setFitBars(true); // make the x-axis fit exactly all bars
        chart.invalidate(); // refresh
```

This library I am using right now for this:

```
implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.3'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all do this:

```
 ArrayList<String> xVals = new ArrayList<String>();
 xVals.add("Jan");
 xVals.add("Feb");
 xVals.add("Mar");
 xVals.add("Apr");
 xVals.add("May");
 xVals.add("Jun");
```

Then customize your Xaxis as below:

```
 XAxis xAxis = chart.getXAxis();
 xAxis.setGranularity(1f);
 xAxis.setGranularityEnabled(true);
 xAxis.setCenterAxisLabels(true);
 xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
 xAxis.setAxisMaximum(6);
 xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);

 // Below line will add labels on your xAxis:

 xAxis.setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter(xVals));
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this:

```
        BarDataSet set = new BarDataSet(entries, "BarDataSet");
        ArrayList<IBarDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<>();
        dataSets.add(set);
        BarData data = new BarData(dataSets);
        data.setBarWidth(0.9f); // set custom bar width
        chart.setData(data);
        chart.setFitBars(true); // make the x-axis fit exactly all bars
        chart.invalidate(); // refres
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. Can you please tell me where exactly you are adding titles here? Because it is not showing title list.